# Windows 8 trackpad gestures along with scrolling stops working after running virtualbox or vmware player

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, touchpad, gestures

I have an AMD A8 based HP laptop, Pavilion G6 2201AX running Windows 8.
It has a Synaptics touchpad. My problem is whenever i run Virtualbox or Vmware player all the gestures on trackpad stop working, even though i can still move the pointer and can perform left click and right click using one and two fingers respectively. I have to restart the laptop in order to get these gestures work again.

What may be the cause of this? Is it a hardware or a software issue? Is there any solution?

Comment: Are your touchpad drivers up to date? Try updating them to the latest version from [Synaptics website](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers).

Comment: Yes, i have upgraded to the latest version but still having the same problem.

Comment: Have you had any luck working around this?  I just ran into the same problem and also tracked it down to my recent installation of Virtualbox  on a Samsung 700T Windows 8 machine.

Comment: No. I updated the synaptics drivers to the latest version but without any luck. As a work around I start the VMs in headless mode (By pressing shift while clicking on start VM) and then connect to it either by RDP, VNC or ssh. I guess this issue has got something to do with guest mouse pointer integration.